# How to properly index multiple fields for faster results

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, rdbms, indexing

I have an index that contains ConChainNum, Control, and TransDate, and I just rebuilt the indexes.  The table I'm working with has over 100 million records and the following query returns no results:

```
select  * from sbt_pos_sales 
where   conchainnum = 810 and 
        control = 852013688 and 
        transdate = 20120712
```

Given that I have an index made specifically with the three fields in the where clause, I really expected an almost immediate result, but it took about half a minute to tell me there where no results.

Can someone explain to me why this index doesn't make it any faster than that, and if I can somehow do it differently to make it faster?

Execution Plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1.1" Build="10.0.5500.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="20.2265" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="348.687" StatementText="SELECT * FROM [ngdwdb]..[sbt_pos_sales] WHERE [conchainnum]=@1 AND [control]=@2 AND [transdate]=@3" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x11B117D9A8C6DF58" QueryPlanHash="0xBA3EFC04623601F6">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="8" MemoryGrant="5504" CachedPlanSize="48" CompileTime="95" CompileCPU="4" CompileMemory="368">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="193" EstimateCPU="0.0655713" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="7330.87" LogicalOp="Gather Streams" NodeId="1" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="348.686">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="RowIdent" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ConChainNum" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Control" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="TransDate" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ControlGS" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="UPC_UCP" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="DateSold" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Price_UCP" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Store" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="QtySold" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="FileName" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="IssueCode" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="DealerNum" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Parallelism>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="193" EstimateCPU="0.00766076" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="7330.87" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="2" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="348.621">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="RowIdent" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ConChainNum" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Control" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="TransDate" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ControlGS" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="UPC_UCP" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="DateSold" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Price_UCP" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Store" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="QtySold" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="FileName" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="IssueCode" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="DealerNum" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="6" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="2" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="3" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="7" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="5" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="4" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="8" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="1" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <NestedLoops Optimized="true" WithUnorderedPrefetch="true">
                    <OuterReferences>
                      <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                    </OuterReferences>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="58" EstimateCPU="14.9196" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="7330.87" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="5" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="324.579">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ConChainNum" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Control" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="TransDate" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <ComputeScalar>
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="BmkToPage([Bmk1000])">
                              <Intrinsic FunctionName="BmkToPage">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Intrinsic>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="58" EstimateCPU="15.196" EstimateIO="294.463" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="7330.87" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="6" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="309.659" TableCardinality="107302000">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ConChainNum" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Control" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="TransDate" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="6" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="3" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="2" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="7" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="8" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="5" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="1" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="4" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ConChainNum" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Control" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="TransDate" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <Object Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Index="[idxLoad]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                            <SeekPredicates>
                              <SeekPredicateNew>
                                <SeekKeys>
                                  <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                    <RangeColumns>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ConChainNum" />
                                    </RangeColumns>
                                    <RangeExpressions>
                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(810)">
                                        <Const ConstValue="(810)" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </RangeExpressions>
                                  </Prefix>
                                </SeekKeys>
                              </SeekPredicateNew>
                            </SeekPredicates>
                            <Predicate>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[NGDWDB].[dbo].[SBT_POS_SALES].[Control],0)=(852013688) AND CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[NGDWDB].[dbo].[SBT_POS_SALES].[TransDate],0)=(20120712)">
                                <Logical Operation="AND">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Control" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Convert>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Const ConstValue="(852013688)" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="TransDate" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Convert>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Const ConstValue="(20120712)" />
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Logical>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Predicate>
                          </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                      </ComputeScalar>
                    </RelOp>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="136" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="7329.87" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="RID Lookup" NodeId="11" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="RID Lookup" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="24.0341" TableCardinality="107302000">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="RowIdent" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ControlGS" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="UPC_UCP" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="DateSold" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Price_UCP" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Store" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="QtySold" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="FileName" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="IssueCode" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="DealerNum" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="6" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="2" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="3" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="7" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="5" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="4" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="8" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="1" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <IndexScan Lookup="true" Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="RowIdent" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="ControlGS" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="UPC_UCP" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="DateSold" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Price_UCP" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="Store" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="QtySold" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="FileName" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="IssueCode" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" Column="DealerNum" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[NGDWDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SBT_POS_SALES]" TableReferenceId="-1" IndexKind="Heap" />
                        <SeekPredicates>
                          <SeekPredicateNew>
                            <SeekKeys>
                              <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Bmk1000]">
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                              </Prefix>
                            </SeekKeys>
                          </SeekPredicateNew>
                        </SeekPredicates>
                      </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </NestedLoops>
                </RelOp>
              </Parallelism>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@3" ParameterCompiledValue="(20120712)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(20120712)" />
              <ColumnReference Column="@2" ParameterCompiledValue="(852013688)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(852013688)" />
              <ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="(810)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(810)" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: There a couple of things that could be slowing it down.  1. how many columns is that * returning?  2, are you always using all 3 columns?  you may need to index seperatly as well.  Did you look at the estimated execution plan?

Comment: Need more information.  Does your index contain other columns or just those three?  Is the index clustered?  If not, is there a clustered index?  Have you checked (and if so, can you post) the execution plan?

Comment: @Limey 1. Thirteen, but why does that matter in this case as no rows are returned?  2. Yes.  I'm looking into the execution plan now.

Comment: @mwigdahl Just the three, and there is no clustered index.  Would having a clustered index speed up other indexes?

Comment: Yes, it certainly could.  If you don't have a clustered index the data is stored as an unordered heap, and fragmentation due to inserts/deletes/etc. can force a lot of cross-page lookups.  In this particular case it doesn't seem reasonable that it would take 30 seconds to return you no rows, but not impossible.  I'd try imposing a clustered index on the table (if that's something you can do) and seeing if that helps.  Always assuming, of course, that the hard data of the execution plan doesn't reveal a more obvious smoking gun.

Comment: @mwigdahl: oops, didn't see it was returning no values.  but if you don't have a clustered index, you should add one

Comment: As Kimberly Tripps shows in her [The Clustered Index Debate Continues....](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) blog post, having a **good** (well picked) clustered index will speed up just about all operations - so (unless you have **very specific** and good reasons) all your tables should have a clustered index

Comment: @mwigdahl I can add one, but I'm just concerned that it will slow down a load process that's already pretty slow.  What seems odd to me is that if I had a word document with these fields listed in order I could probably scroll through it and find that there are no results in less than 30 seconds (disregarding memory issues Word might have with that much data, of course).  Even without a clustered index, it still seems odd to me that it should take so long.  And FYI, the execution plan doesn't reveal anything obvious.  I will try to post a pic of it a little later.

Comment: @marc_s I guess what I don't understand is that I am thinking of an index as being like looking at the index at the back of a book.  Even if the pages of the book weren't in order, I would think the index would still be in order and I would be able to see that there are no entries pretty quickly.  So I'm wondering what's actually going on in SQL that it can't do that?

Comment: @BrandonMoore I'll be happy to look at the plan when you get a chance to post it.

Comment: @mwigdahl Sorry the pic turned out real small... if you can't read it let me know and I'll try again.  Or if there is any info other than the pic that I can get for you then just let me know how to pull it up and I will.

Comment: Can't read the picture.  You should be able to right-click on it and get the XML tree that SSMS uses to build the picture.  If you can post that I can look at it in my own SSMS.

Comment: actually never mind, I can read it via the link.

Comment: What are the types of `ConChainNum`, `Control` and `TransDate`? In fact, could you please show us the complete CREATE TABLE and INDEX?

Comment: The query execution plan does show that the `index seek` is being used --> so the query is going through the index, as fast as it can (using a seek - not a scan). So I don't see what more you could really do - except maybe not selecting using `SELECT *` (but instead specify only the columns that are part of the index -> that would eliminate the need for the `RID lookups` that are happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than keep filling up the comments, I'll formalize this as an answer...

Based on your execution plan, I recommend adding a clustered index on the table.  It's hard to be 100% sure what's going on, but RID lookups are a problem.

RID lookups are what happens when there's not a clustering key associated with the table.  In a nonclustered index, the clustering key gets replicated in the nonclustered index if there is one, speeding up any row access required after the index entries are found.  In a heap (a table with a nonclustered index) you don't have that clustering key, so you have to look it up in the heap.

That's why you have an `INNER JOIN` in the execution plan, even though there's no `JOIN` in your SQL.  Applying clustering to the primary key in the table should eliminate this join, and leave it with a simple index seek.

Although the current plan shows it burning 89% of your time right now, I'll bet that with a clustered index on the table you'll simplify it down to a simple (and much faster) index seek.

EDIT:

Let me amend this after looking at your execution plan XML.  Although the clustering key should still help, the real problem is the data types in your indexes.  On the index seek I'm showing

`CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[NGDWDB].[dbo].[SBT_POS_SALES].[Control],0)=(852013688) AND CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[NGDWDB].[dbo].[SBT_POS_SALES].[TransDate],0)=(20120712)`

, which is telling me that Control and TransDate are not the same data types as you are providing in your query.  If you fix this up such that no conversions are required, you will very likely see a huge speedup in the query.

Comment: Thanks.  Here's a side question for you if you know the answer: If I did a bulk insert into this table (which I understand ignores the indexes), would it be important for me to rebuild the indexes every time I did one or just periodically (like maybe once a week, if I do a bulk insert once a day of about 30k rows)?

Comment: THe other option would be to only select the columns that are part of the index - that would eliminate the need for any `RID lookups` (or `Key lookups` once a clustered index is in place)

Comment: Aha, the conversions were the biggest culprit and doing "select 1" instead of * helps too.  Now I have the immediate results I was looking for.  Thanks guys!